# PHP arrays: How can I get the arrays that don't have a 0 value

Tags: php

How can I extract or get the value of the array with [hits] that is greater than 0?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hits] => 0
            [date] => 2011-09-29 17:58:25
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hits] => 1
            [date] => 2011-09-29 16:55:42
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hits] => 1
            [date] => 2011-09-29 17:54:38
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hits] => 1
            [date] => 2011-09-29 17:58:25
        )
    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hits] => 0
            [date] => 2011-09-29 17:58:25
        )
    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hits] => 3
            [date] => 2011-09-29 17:58:25
        )

)
```

Comment: @stereorog: I agree, also check [`printf()` converter](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eVhuuJ) by [hakre](http://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's not array of arrays, but array of objects. Just loop trough them and do a conditional check. Like this:

```
<?php 
$with_hits = array();
foreach ($objects as $object){
  if ($object->hits > 0){
    $with_hits[] = $object;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming >= PHP 5.3...

```
$newArr = array_filter($arr, function($obj) {
    return $obj->hits > 0;
});
```

Comment: The arguments need to be swapped though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk` or `array_map` function to test `hits`.

```
$hits = array();

function fill_hits($key, $item)
{
    global $hits;
    if ($item->hits > 0) $hits[] = $obj;
}

array_walk('fill_hits', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$ret = array();
foreach($data as $key => $obj) {
    if($obj->hits > 0) {
        $ret[$key] = $obj;
    }
}

print_r($ret); // your filtered data here

?>
```